# properly populate a list in a map

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a map whose value is a list of integers. I have to add an integer to the list if the key is found in a reader. The code I have below works for every time except one. In other words, if the key exists 5 times, the list will say it only has 4 times. What am I missing? Thanks!

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>();
String key; // the string from my reader

if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.get(key).add(value); //value being an integer gotten earlier
}
```

My code has the keys being added to the map in a constructor like so:

```
while (reader.ready()) {
    key = reader.readLine();
    if(!key.isEmpty()) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
}
```

I don't need to do anything if the key isn't found, just add the value when it is.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you posted isn't your actual full code, but in any case you need to have logic to handle the first time a key is seen.  In this first case, you should be initializing a list of integers to be stored in the map.   Something like this:

```
public static void addValue(String key, Integer value,
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map) {
    List<Integer> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    list.add(value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    String key; // the string from my reader
    Integer value;
    addValue(key, value, map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle if the key is not found? I suspect that you miss to add the first Integer value to the list if the key is not found.

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.get(key).add(value); //value being an integer gotten earlier
} else {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(value); //add value to the list
    map.put(key, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you solve problem.

```
//if key not exists insert key    
    if(!map.containsKey(key)){
           List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           list.add(value);
           map.put(key,list);
        }
    //if key exists do this...
    else{
          List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          //Getting previous existing elements on map at that index and adding to list back
          list.addAll(map.get(key));
          map.put(list);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned that you want to modified same list which is not but map value only if it is same list you can use java 8

```
map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        if ("5" == entry.getKey()) {
            ((List) entry.getValue()).add(5);
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use computeIfAbsent:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(yourValue);
```